# getting .append values from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the function below, I'm finding the max count of an ID then adding 1. Everything works, except the new values being added to the DOM aren't seen, therefore they are not incremented upon calling the function a second time.

Am I not adding the new values to the DOM correctly?

```
function addEdu(){
    var currentCount = $('input.uniqueId').val();
    currentCount = Math.max(currentCount);
    var nextCount = parseInt(currentCount) + 1;
    var newEdu = "<input type='hidden' name='fieldId[]' value='" + nextCount + "' class='uniqueId' /><p class='dual'><input type='text' name='educationTitle[]' "; //Shortened for clarity
    $("#eduHistory").append(newEdu); 
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
}
```

Comment: seems correct...are you calling this function inside a `$(document).ready(function() { //code here }` block?

Comment: var currentCount = $('input.uniqueId').val(); You should be doing this in a .each() operation because you're not being explicit about which value you're trying to get. Or maybe you want .size() instead of .val()?

Comment: @rnirnber - surely you meant `length`, not `size()` ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: @rnirnber - my point exactly -> "the .length property is preferred" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're trying to determine the next `.uniqueId` is wrong.
First of all, `$("input.uniqueId").val()` will give you the value of the first element in the selection.
The second problem is with `Math.max(currentCount)` which will always return the value of `currentCount` which is, as already mentioned, the value of the first element.

This should work as intended:

```
// get an array with all uniqueIds
var currentIds = $("input.uniqueId").map(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});

// determine the biggest uniqueId
var currentCount = Math.max.apply(Math, currentIds);

// next uniqueId (if there is no "input.uniqueId" then currentCount will be -Infinity)
var nextCount = (currentCount === -Infinity ? 0 : currentCount) + 1;

// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('input.uniqueId').val()` will give you the value of the first input with class `uniqueId`. If you are only expecting there to be one such input just change the value of the input. Otherwise you'll probably have to select the last input `$('input.uniqueId:last').val()`.

Also Math.max takes 2 parameters, what is its purpose?

Comment: I'll have an unknown number of values for `$('input.uniqueId').val()`. I'm trying to increment the value of `uniqueId` by 1 upon creation. `Math.max` is my attempt to get the maximum value of `$('input.uniqueId').val()`

Comment: @relentless `var ids = $("input.uniqueId").map(function() { return parseInt($(this).val(), 10); }); var currentCount = Math.max.apply(Math, ids);`

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks! Just tried it and it looks like it's working perfectly. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept.